# Database not creating record

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Inserting a record in the database using EF 5.0 isn't working. Debugging through my code I cannot find any exception. Going through the code it should insert a new record in the database, but when I look at the database there are no new records created. However, I did make changes to my database, and in debug when I check on the "assestUser" (the model) I can see all values, including the deleted columns (the changes I made). Could somebody please help me with what I am doing wrong?
This is what I have done:

Page:

```
   public partial class _Default : Page
{
    EntityContext context;

    public _Default()
    {
        context = new EntityContext();
    }

     protected void btnSavePersonalDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SkillsAssestUser assestUser = new SkillsAssestUser();
            assestUser.DomainAcc = lblDomAcc.Text;
            assestUser.Name = txtName.Text;
            assestUser.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
            assestUser.Division = txtDivision.Text;
            assestUser.Manager = txtManager.Text;


            context.SkillsAssestUsers.Add(assestUser);
            context.SaveChanges();


            //var assestUser = context.Set<SkillsAssestUser>();
            //assestUser.Add(new SkillsAssestUser
            //{
            //    DomainAcc = lblDomAcc.Text,
            //    Name = txtName.Text,
            //    Surname = txtSurname.Text,
            //    Division = txtDivision.Text,
            //    Manager = txtManager.Text
            //});

            //context.SaveChanges();

            ClearPersonalDetails();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error inserting Details. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

DbContext:

```
 public partial class EntityContext : DbContext
 {
    public EntityContext()
        : base("name=SOSConnectionString")
    {
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

     #region AddTables
    public DbSet<AdditionalSkills> AdditionalSkillss { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CertifiedTraining> CertifiedTrainings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OtherCertifiedTraining> OtherCertifiedTrainings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OtherEdu> OtherEdus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SchoolEdu> SchoolEdus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SkillsAssestUser> SkillsAssestUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ValueAddedSkills> ValueAddedSkillss { get; set; } 
    #endregion
    }

     void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
        Database.SetInitializer<EntityContext>(null);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? ...new to ef....

Comment: IMO, worth asking, are you copying the database file to the output directory on every build or do you use a SQL Server?

Comment: @Alex, Hi, no I'm not copying db files to the output directory on every build... I've used ef 4.1 in an windows application before, and this worked there....

Comment: Have you checked the types of the values you are assigning?

Comment: Yes, all the types are correct....

Comment: well the code seems correct..If possible(i know its not right way) but can u again regenerate the ef from scratch..

Comment: I'm actually busy doing it right now... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Connection String First.

be sure that this is on Global.ASAX:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Code that runs on application startup
    AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
    Database.SetInitializer<EntityContext>(null);
 }
```

use code like this:

```
      using (var mycontext = new context())
        {
           SkillsAssestUser assestUser = new SkillsAssestUser();
           assestUser.DomainAcc = lblDomAcc.Text;
           assestUser.Name = txtName.Text;
           assestUser.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
           assestUser.Division = txtDivision.Text;
           assestUser.Manager = txtManager.Text;

           mycontext.SkillsAssestUsers.Add(assestUser);
           mycontext.SaveChanges();
        }
```